# Gamecontroller support on Asus Transformer

Tags: android, gamecontroller

I'm trying to connect several gamecontrollers to my Asus Transformer (not prime).

I got a Logitech F310, F710 and XBox 360 controller for windows.

On Android 3.2.1 the F310 worked, and the XBox controller failed (f710 not tested).
Now I have updated Android to 4.0 but now all 3 won't work. For the logitechs I have tried the DirectInput and XInput toggle.

I'm using

```
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)
```

To receive the MotionEvent events.

On the Tegra website there is a mention that F710 and the XBox controller should work:
http://www.tegrazone.com/support/game-controller-support
But this is for Tegra 3. I got a Tegra 2.

Anyone know how to get them working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this a long time ago, compiling the sources of TF101 with the extra drivers enabled fixed this.

If someone needs the drivers you can find them here: [Gamepad modules for Android 4.0.3 + KeyLayout files](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1584850)